# How to add text with a revealing effect

Tags: text, animation, effects, adobe-after-effects, animated-gif

I want the text to be revealed as the scroll opens. How can I achieve this? I want my effect to come off exactly like this sample GIF just that I want to add my own text.[image: text reveal effect]

Comment: If it's for commercial use, you shouldn't just replace the logo with your own in this graphic. If it's for a meme, that might be more or a gray area... Either way I'm pretty sure this is the same exact item https://videohive.net/item/old-scroll-parchment-blank/6418074 don't know how the file is constructed but usually they are made in such a way that even beginners can fairly easily replace or add their own graphic

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Video editing is generally off-topic here. Sorry about that. Try asking on video production stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it with flat footage (only a video of a scroll unravelling) would be to mask the text with the pen tool, making the edges of the mask the edges of the scroll.